# How to classify the hydride shift in the following diazacyclopenta[cd]pentalene system?

Tags: organic-chemistry, pericyclic

How is this hydride shift reaction type called?

[image]

I think it's not one of following types:

- cycloaddition (Diels Alder)
- electrocyclic ring opening
- sigmatropic rearrangement
- ene reaction
- cheleotropic reaction

Therefore I'm thinking what else can been the name of the observed reaction.

The ring opening reaction with hydride shift has been taken from *Heterocycles* **2004,** *64* (1), 447–461 ([DOI: 10.3987/COM-04-S(P)48](http://doi.org/10.3987/COM-04-S(P)48)).

Comment: The back reaction looks like an "ene" reaction to me.  The forward reaction would then be a "retro-ene" reaction.

Comment: I also wrote "ene" in the exam. The reason why I'm unsure now is the existing C(H)-N bond: I thought a ene-reaction happens with two unconnected species as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ene_reaction

Comment: No, the pieces can be connected. See [this pdf](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/organic/studsemin/wysocki/wysocki-sem.pdf) for some "connected" hetero-ene examples.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to see what was actually happening. Initially, I was focused on a [1,5] suprafacial sigmatropic proton shift followed by a diaza-electrocyclic ring opening reaction. However, after drawing the corresponding orbitals I realised that I would have a eight-electron antiaromatic π system, in which a proton shift would need to occur antarafacially — not possible.<sup>[1]</sup>

It still is clear that it is some kind of [pericyclic reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pericyclic_reaction), and going through the list we can exclude everything except for a (retro-) group transfer reaction for which the (retro-) ene reaction is the most well-known example. (We are transforming one σ bond into one π bond which excludes all the others.)

It took me a while to actually *see* the retro-ene system in the substrate, but finally I did, and I took the liberty of highlighting it in red in the scheme below. Note that you have to ignore the carbon-nitrogen bond which belongs to the lowest five-membered ring from the ene-system. It is not taking part, if anything it is scaffolding.

[image: hydride shift with bonds taking part in red]
Scheme 1: Retro-ene reaction of the title compound with the pericyclic six-membered ring system highlighted. Dashed bonds represent those that are broken/formed within the reaction.

Counting electrons, I realised that my initial assumption of a proton shift was wrong and that it is indeed a hydride shift.

---

**Notes:**

[1] [1,*n*]-rearrangements are classified as *suprafacial* or *antarafacial* depending on whether the group is on the same side or the other side of a π system after migration. Technically, there is a further difference between retention and inversion, but hydrogen cannot rearrange under inversion so that is moot. The general rule for proton transfers is: If the number of bonds is $4n + 1$, the mechanism is suprafacial, for $4n + 3$ it is antarafacial.